# How to use look-at feature in Ar.js programatically

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, ar.js

I am trying to use the look-at feature of Ar.js dynamically through js. But for some reason, the 3d-object is not looking out of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answering the topic

You can set the [look-at](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/look-at) component using javascript, by adding it to any `a-frame` entity:

```
// using an existing entity as a target
entity.setAttribute("look-at", "#selector");
// using a Vector3 position as target 
entity.setAttribute("look-at", {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0})
```

### Answering this specific case

The `look-at` component (and the used by it `lookAt` method) assume, that the model is orented towards the z-axis.

The duck model is oriented towards the `x` axis.
If it's possible, reorient the model in a 3D modelling software like blender.
If not, then you can use a parent node to reorient it:

```
<!-- Parent node will look at the user--/>
<a-entity look-at="[camera]">
    <!-- Child node with the rotation offset--/>
    <a-entity rotation="0 -90 0" gltf-model ....>
```

Check it out [in this glitch](https://stack-62996415.glitch.me/)

If there are more models, you can create a rotation offset array, and apply it to the `[gltf-model]` node each time you load a new model.

---

The `<a-camera>` already contains a `camera`. To change its properties just use the `<a-camera>` [attributes](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/primitives/a-camera.html):

```
<a-camera fov="60" ....></a-camera>
```

Comment: sorry for not showing the part where I call `showobj()`, but I do call it and that part works fine. Secondly, my first Idea was to add the rotation parameter to the gltf model only, but the problem with this solution is that I cannot be sure that this rotation value will work on other objects as well, as they might have different orientation along different axis. So I was trying to use lookat feature to make any 3d-object to start looking at me(out of the screen) from the moment they are loaded.

Comment: @abhishekranjan both the `look-at` component, and the `lookAt` method assume, that the models are oriented towards the z-axis. Neither a-frame, nor three.js won't know what is "supposed" to be the front of the model if its incorrectly oriented. If it's possible - reorient the models in a modelling software (blender), if not - you'll need to keep an array of offsets for each model.

Comment: oh okay,that was helpful. I didn't knew that.Many thanks.I'll try to reorient the model first.if that doesn't work, I'll will follow your second solution (which was basically the first solution given by you).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the lookAt method on the object3D of your entity. Something like this :

```js
var camera = document.querySelector("[camera]");
var position = camera.object3D.position;
entityEl.object3D.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(position.x, position.y, position.z));
```

Comment: It will orient the object once. The mentioned [look-at](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/look-at/index.js) component is calling `lookAt` upon each tick.

Comment: Oh okay I didn't get that and did not know this component, seems useful, thanks for the information! :)